# How do I disable Codeigniter _GET Query Strings?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I thought Codeigniter removed the ability to retrieve _GET data from the url and added its own function where you can retrieve URI segments. eg. `localhost/controller/method/10`

Today after I updated to Codeigniter 2.1.0 I tried `$this->input->get('data')` and in my url `localhost/controller/method?data=10` and it worked. Did I somehow break my Codeigniter install or is this functinatity supposed to be here now?

In my `config/config.php` file I found the following two lines:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

I thought that the first line would just enable Codeigniter's GET method of using URI segments eg. controller/method/data/moredata. While the second one would enable query strings eg. ?data=10.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: If you remove the QSA flag from the .htaccess then ?data=10 would not get passed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LawrenceCherone but when I removed QSA flag from my .htaccess file it did not change a thing. I even restarted my local MAMP server just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

> thought that the first line would just enable Codeigniter's GET method
>   of using URI segments. While the second one would enable query
>   strings.

AFAIK, you're right for the second one, while for the first it simply mean that the $_GET array is not "destroyed and purified" by the Input class. Specifically, I refer to the `_sanitize_global()` method in the input class, which has these lines of code:

```
// Is $_GET data allowed? If not we'll set the $_GET to an empty array
        if ($this->_allow_get_array == FALSE)
        {
            $_GET = array();
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_array($_GET) AND count($_GET) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
                {
                    $_GET[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);
                }
            }
        }
```

> I looked in the user guide and there is a section on
>   $this->input->get() but I thought that was just talking about the
>   Codeigniter's way with URI segments.

Looks like you're looking/referring to the `$this->uri->segment(n)` method, which fetch the specified *n* segment inside the uri string; which is (very) roughly the equivalent of fetching a query param in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use $_GET with codeigniter, just use `$this->uri->segment(n)` to get variable from url, segment acording to your url, ex

```
http://localhost/myweb/index.php/controller/function/myvar
```

then segment 1 is controller 2 is function and 3 is myvar, thats it, clear and secure i guest :D